# Passing information from shaders to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, shader, webgl

WebGL is shader based. In my shaders I can write code like

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = a + b;
```

Is there a way to extract the value of `c` from shader-land to JavaScript-land?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of a WebGL drawing pass is writes to the render target color buffer. You will need to study up on GPGPU programming with OpenGL and WebGL specifically. See this blog post for a discussion on doing GPGPU with WebGL:

https://mchouza.wordpress.com/2011/02/21/gpgpu-with-webgl-solving-laplaces-equation/